# Load different config files based on domain requested for the same .net instance

Tags: c#, .net, path, web-config

We have a .net web application, we want to point two domains(ex: xxtest . com and yytest . com) to the same application. I need to have different appsettings values for keys based on domain in aspx.cs file.
when i request ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Serverkey1"] how can i configure or code so that i get different values based on the domain (xxtest . com/yytest . c om)

Thank You

Comment: Would it be possible for you to do it by checking the request host like so: Request.Url.Host?

Comment: no, we are accessing app settings in many places, its really huge application. So instead of adding if condition, i am looking for another solution. Something in the lines of having multiple config files or some how dynamically change values based on request

Comment: Interesting. Looking forward to seeing what answers will come. Another possible solution is to name your AppSettings["DOMAINNAME_KEY"], then you could do something like ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[Request.Url.Host + "serverkey"] :)

Comment: yes, i still have to change it in a lot of places with this approach and we have many applications to change as well. waiting to see for other answers

Answer (score 0):

All you should need is the

```
string domain = Request.Url.Host;
```

Then you can do a simple string comparison and do whatever you want.

Useful Link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri.host?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Uri_Host